# Show loader on Export CSV and hide once download completes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, csv, download, loader

I want to generate & download csv file on link and want to show loader before download starts and hide loader after finishing in my rails application.
I have tried:-

**index.html**

```
<%= link_to 'Export to CSV', shifts_export_csv_admin_shifts_path(format: :csv), id: 'export_ink', class: 'download_csv_link', remote: true %>
```

**shifts_controller.rb**

```
def shifts_export_csv
   respond_to do |format|
     format.csv { send_data @shifts.to_csv, filename: "shifts-#{Date.today}.csv" }
   end
end
```

**admin.js**

```
$(document).on('ajax:beforeSend', 'a[data-remote=true]', function(event, xhr, status, error) {
  $('.ajax-loader-container').show();
});
$(document).on('ajax:success', 'a[data-remote=true]', function(){
  $('.ajax-loader-container').hide();
});
```

Issue is when i am using `remote: true` in `link_to`, loader is working fine but file is not downloading, and when i am **NOT** using `remote: true` file is downloading but loader is showing but not hiding after download completes.

Thanks in advance